# CreateObjectURL for local file system

Tags: javascript, html

Why is there a "No Function was found" error?

```
block head


script.
   function convert_local_file()  {
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
     , file = this.file; 
    var value = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL("file:///home/sanika/NodeJS/Projects/project1/routes/../videosTrans/Node.js tutorial for beginners - an introduction to Node.js with Express2.js.mp4"); 
    return value; 
   }


block content
      video(id="videolink" width="400" height="320" type="video/mp4" controls)
       script.
             document.getElementById('videolink').src = convert_local_file();
```

IMAGE:
 [image]

Comment: How is the error you get in any way related to node or jade? Please post only the script of interest

Comment: what are you trying to create?

Comment: @Jason Nichols : I want to display the video which is in the local file system in the browser.

Comment: the `/../` is not a valid path, is it, or are you just trying to shorten it for readability?

Comment: createObjectURL waits for a File or Blob

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what your end goal is, but your reference to createObjectURL in your function is probably incorrect. What you want to do is grab the local file using an input tag.

```js
class LocalFileVideoPlayer {
    constructor(input, video) {
        this.input = input;
        this.video = video;
        this.input.addEventListener('change', this.onChange, false);
    }

    static createObjectURL(obj) {
        return (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(obj);
    }

    onChange = () => {
        const [file] = this.input.files;
        if (!file) {
            alert('No file selected');
            return;
        }
        if (!this.video.canPlayType(file.type)) {
            alert('Cannot play video of type ' + file.type);
            return;
        }
        this.playVideo(file);
    }

    destroy = () => {
        this.input.removeEventListener('change', this.onChange, false);
        this.input = null;
        this.video = null;
    }

    playVideo = (file) => {
        var url = LocalFileVideoPlayer.createObjectURL(file);
        this.video.src = url;
    }
}

var localFileVideoPlayer = new LocalFileVideoPlayer(
    document.querySelector('input'),
    document.querySelector('video')
);
```

```css
video, input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="video/*" />
<video controls autoplay></video>
```